# Native Functions meaning?

Tags: function, native, nlp-question-answering

What "Native functions" means or refers to, in a programming language?

I am reading the book "Crafting Interpreters" by Robert Nystrom where he has a list on Github with all Lox's implementations that other readers have done in other languages. I saw that one of that list says that it does not have native functions and I would like to know what it means about that?

https://github.com/munificent/craftinginterpreters/wiki/Lox-Implementations

Comment: Probably refers to http://craftinginterpreters.com/calls-and-functions.html#native-functions

Comment: Thank you very much! @UnholySheep  I haven't gotten to that part of the book yet, however, I finally understood what Native functions mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Native Function Definition, from the book "Crafting Interpreters" by Robert Nystrom

http://craftinginterpreters.com/calls-and-functions.html#native-functions